# How to remove url from Cache in okhttp?

Tags: java, android, caching, iterator, okhttp

I use Retrofit 2 library with okhttp3 to make API calls in my android app. I need to invalidate cache for some specific urls after some operations(invalidate get posts after creating a new post).

On the internet everyone says I need to get Cache iterator and remove the url by calling remove() method but no one shows how to do it properly. I am trying to remove the very first url from the cache in this way:

```
Cache.urls().next().remove()
```

But because urls() method is non-static, it does not work. I do not know how to get okhttp cache instance either. When I try

```
Cache cache = new Cache(this.getCacheDir(), 10000);
cache.urls().next();
```

inside `MainActivity` I get `java.util.NoSuchElementException` this time.

```
Failed to load DynamiteLoader: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.os.IBinder com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper.asBinder()' on a null object reference
09-17 11:37:38.868 21171-21171/com.elmxana.elmxana E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: com.elmxana.elmxana, PID: 21171
                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.elmxana.elmxana/com.elmxana.elmxana.MainActivity}: java.util.NoSuchElementException
```

Can you please help me to find exact solution to invalidate cache for specific url?

Comment: have you tried to retrieve cache from okhttp object?

Comment: I tried, but cannot not find a way to do it. If you do, please write it. If you know full answer to my question and post it here I would be very glad.

Comment: okhttpClient.cache() gives you the cache which you previously set to the client.

Comment: btw the error log doesn't point to the okhttp cache error. are you sure the error is coming due to url methods ?

Comment: I tried okhttpClient = new OkHttpClient.builder.build(); okhttpClient.urls().next(). App crashed with an error saying that invoke urls() method on null object reference. Didn't I get cache correctly?

Comment: Have you added cache to the ok http builder? Cause while building the client you have to provide a cache object to it

Comment: I don't provide any cache instance to the client. But I get cached response everytime I send a request. Isn't that due to okhttp implicit caching? if not, where should I look in order to control response caching?

Answer (score 2):

Removing individual items can be done using the urls iterator. This would be typical after a user initiates a force refresh by a pull to refresh type action.

```
val urlIterator = cache.urls()
while (urlIterator.hasNext()) {
  if (urlIterator.next().startsWith("https://www.google.com/")) {
    urlIterator.remove()
  }
}
```

ref: https://square.github.io/okhttp/caching/#pruning-the-cache